# Table in Ant design : Passing string to render method in column attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, antd

I am using Ant design in my react project and and want to add the string to the render attribute for the column structure.

Here is a usual code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from 'antd';

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    render: text => <a>{text}</a> // <<<< Want to pass string here
  }

];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',

  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
   },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
   },
];

ReactDOM.render(<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Now in the above code I am passing JSX code in a string to render in column. But I am having string that I want to render.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from 'antd';

const fun = "text => <a>{text}</a>"  // this string I want to render

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    render: fun // <<<< no passing string here I do know I need to covert this string into something
  }

];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',

  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
   },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
   },
];

ReactDOM.render(<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

What approach do I need to follow to run and execute the code which will give me same result as above.

NOTE: I am getting this string from the Back-end

Any help to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same pattern instead of using as a string like instead of

```
const fun = "text => <a>{text}</a>"
```

You can write as:

```
const fun = text => <a>{text}</a>
```

Please check the demo at:

[image: Edit antd-menu-click-rendering].

Comment: I am getting rendering content in a string format. That is the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue using the templating language. I have used the squirrelly templating language.

As you see in the below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from 'antd';
import * as sqrl from "squirrelly";

const render = "<a>{{data}}</a>"

const htmlNode = (text) =>{
  /**
   *we are formating a data in the particular format so that
   *we can use it along with squirrelly templating
   */ 
  const data  = {data : text} 
  /**
   * In the below code we are ,merging the html string and data together 
  */
  const __html = sqrl.Render(render, data || []); 
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html}}/> 
}

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    render: text => htmlNode(text)
  }

];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',

  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
   },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
   },
];

ReactDOM.render(<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```